# How to add external jar files to maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am using the maven shade plugin to create shade jar file, in that jar the jars under **Maven Dependencies** library are get included, so along with that I want the jar under lib folder also get included.
The following is the project structure. please suggest any solution.Thanks in advance.

[image: my project structure]
The plugin I used as :

```
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <finalName>spg_getperson</finalName>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>tibjms:tibjms</artifact>
                    <includes>
                         <include>${pom.basedir}/lib/tibjms.jar</include>
                     </includes>
                </filter>
                 <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                       <excludes>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                       </excludes>
                    </filter>
                 </filters>
                <transformers>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>com.uprr.app.spg.components.xmfservice.peoplesoft.GetPersonDataService</mainClass>
                  </transformer>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                  </transformer>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                  </transformer>
                  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                  </transformer>
                </transformers>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

Plugin "maven-shade-plugin" takes only maven dependencies.
You can install all non-maven libs in local (or remote) maven repository with maven-install-plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Smth. like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sample.jar -DgroupId=org.sample -DartifactId=sample -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```